# is there a simple code for adding a border to all elements in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, border

i was forced to migrate from a theme and want to make the new one look similar. i couldnt find anything on google, so i thought if i ask here perhaps in will help me and others in the future.

for example, a box around all blog posts and widgets on the front page.

i tried this

```
`{ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
   box-sizing: border-box; }`
```

but in all honesty i dont even know what it does. it was just the only answer on google that looked similar - and it didnt do anything to my site.

Comment: Share your wordpress URL and Ill give you some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks very much Nico. if anyone has the exact same problem, adding this code into the child theme worked for me:

```
article {
 border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    }

.widget-container {
 border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    }
```

Comment: this code adds a border on all pages. i'll work out how to add one on just the front page tonight and update it.

Answer (score 1):

Like your tags show, you know, that you are working with CSS there.
This line of css is switching your page elements to border-box (which is a good thing). This will add the padding and border to element's width (http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

If you want to add a border to certain elements, you should know how to identify these elements. You will find `class` attributes in the HTML of your blog (for example `<div class="posting"> ... </div>`.

You could know add this css, to add a red border to all divs with`class="posting"`

```
.posting
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Or if you dare, you could add a border to everything.. But i don't think you really want that

```
*
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. if anyone has the  exact same problem adding this code into the child theme worked for me:

'
article {
 border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  }

.widget-container {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  }
'